# Icloud storage plan

Tags: storage

I kept receiving Full memory on the iphone so I changed the storage plan to 50 GB.
It's been almost a week, I checked the payment, it's been succesfully done, yet the storage is not updated on the phone.
Any idea what action should I take?
Many thanks,
Cristina